# classes missing in Eclipse package, help

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I want to do a small plugin with a single command which prints the current project name. The code fragment is a below:

```
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

    IEditorPart editorPart = window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    if (editorPart != null){
        IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput)editorPart.getEditorInput() ;
        IFile file = input.getFile();
        IProject activeProject = file.getProject();
        String activeProjectName = activeProject.getName();
        //... use activeProjectName 
    }
```

Problem: IFileEditorInput cannot be found(error msg: cannot be resolved to a type). I have import org.eclipse.ui.*; at the top of the file, but it doesn't work.  Seems that IFileEditorInput is missing, but how I can find it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a dependency on the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in. `IFileEditorInput` lives in the `org.eclipse.ui` *package*, but not the *plug-in* of the same name, which is confusing. You can also avoid this type of confusion by using *package dependencies* rather than depending explicitly on certain plug-ins.